# Laravel one-to-many update

Tags: laravel, one-to-many

I have two (amongst other) models: Product and Category. Category has many products.

So far I am updating a record like this:

```
public function update(Product $product)
    {
        $product->update([Input::all(), 'category_id' => Input::get('category_id')]);
        return redirect('product');
    }
```

And I can't seem to get why can't I omit the `category_id` part? If I don't put it there it doesn't get updated, although the JSON output is like so:

```
{
"_token": "...",
"name": "Omnis",
"description": "Molestiae vel aut et doloremque.",
"price": "48",
"category_id": "5",
"_method": "PUT",
"save": "Save"
}
```

Comment: Do you have `category_id` in your `$fillable` array for Product model?

Comment: Yes I do...strange...I will debug it further...

Comment: To update a belongsTo relationship (set category_id) you could use `$product->associate($category); $product->save()`.